# Issue in getting value from textfield in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, textfield

I am new to flutter.
I am trying to place 2 textfields namely Email and password.
And one login button.
If the user click login button, I want to check the value in text field. If it's "username and password = admin" I want to print a message "Login successful". 
To get the value in text field, I used **controller** to get the text. but if i use controller when **i switch to next textfield the value in first is deleted automatically**. i don't know what is the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'stacked_icons.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
final emailController =  TextEditingController();
final passwordController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
  statusBarColor: Colors.orange, //or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
));

return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor:Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFF18D191))),
  body: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new StakedIcons(),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 80.0),
              child: new Text(
                "Village",
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Padding(
          padding:
          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 0.0),

          child: TextField(

              controller: emailController,
            decoration:
            new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
          ),
        ),
        new SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding:
          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 0.0),
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
            //controller: passwordController
          ),
        ),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0, right: 5.0, top: 10.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint(passwordController.text+emailController.text);
                 },
                  child: new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 60.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFF18D191),
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
                      child: new Text("Login",
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white))),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                child: new Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 60.0,
                    child: new Text("Forgot Password?",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17.0, color: Color(0xFF18D191)))),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:18.0),
                child: new Text("Create A New Account ",style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17.0, color: Color(0xFF18D191),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

If i remove the controller, The value in the textfield is working. But without using controller i don't know hot to get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Stateless widget, which means an entirely new instance of it is created every time the UI changes, such as when you switch to the next field. This includes your controllers - they are reinitialized when you change focus from one field to another, which is why they reset to blank values.

You need to use a Stateful widget, and have the controllers initialized outside of the `build()` method. That way, when the UI changes it is rebuilt, but the State of the widget including your controllers and their values are persisted.

If you are using Android Studio, all you need to do is click anywhere on this line `class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {` then press Alt+Enter then click "Convert to StatefulWidget". There is a shortcut for it in VSCode as well but I don't know it.

Comment: Thank you so much. it's worked. I am new to flutter and dart. Now only starting from hello world. can you please suggest me any good tutorial point to learn the basics.

Comment: Tutorials are listed at https://flutter.io/docs/reference/tutorials.  I'd also highly recommend the codelabs at https://flutter.io/docs/codelabs.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `email` and `password` fields into a `Form` widget and to change their type to `TextFormField` to provide a `validator` function so it can be called when you press the button:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(

  key: _formKey,

 child: Column(
 children: <widget>[
   Padding(
      padding:
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 0.0),

      child: TextFormField(
        controller: emailController,
        decoration:
        new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
        validator: //Your validator function here
      ),
    ),
    new SizedBox(
      height: 15.0,
    ),
    Padding(
      padding:
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 0.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
        //controller: passwordController,
        validator: //Your validator function here
        ),
      ),
      new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20.0, right: 5.0, top: 10.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint(passwordController.text+emailController.text);
                 if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                    //This will only be reached if there both fields has valid input
                 }

             },
              child: new Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 60.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xFF18D191),
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
                  child: new Text("Login",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white))),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
            child: new Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 60.0,
                child: new Text("Forgot Password?",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 17.0, color: Color(0xFF18D191)))),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    ]
  ),
),
```

This is an example of a `validator` function for your Email field :

```
 validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Email is required' : null
```

`val` is the current text on the field, so when the result is `null` the form will know that `val` is valid input, otherwise it won't submit.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the `onChanged` parameter of `TextField` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/TextField.html

```
TextField('foo', onChanged((s) => setState(() => myText = s)))
```